# How to relaunch an electron/react application on crash

Tags: reactjs, electron

I have an application built with react and electron, here is the issue that is occurring.

Sometimes when launching the application it will have an uncaught exception because of some IPC communication that failed.

I added a handler for this in my electron entry point file according to the documentation. However, when it relaunches it does not launch MY application. It simply displays some electron template window.

[image: Electron Template]

Here is the handler I'm using:

```
    process.on("uncaughtException", function (err) {
    //log the message and stack trace
    log.warn("uncaught Exception: ", err);
    //relaunch the app
    app.relaunch({ args: [] });
    app.exit(0);
    handleLaunch(tray, window, store, __dirname);
  });
```

The handleLaunch function is as such:

```
// Library Imports
const { app, BrowserWindow, dialog } = require("electron");
const { autoUpdater } = require("electron-updater");
const log = require("electron-log");
//Functions
const { createIpcBusBridge } = require("../ipc/createIpcBusBridge");
const { createWindow } = require("../window/createWindow");
const { createTray } = require("../tray/createTray");

const handleLaunch = (tray, window, store, directoryName) => {
  const isDev = !app.isPackaged;
  if (isDev === true) {
    const reactDevToolsId = "fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi";
    const {
      default: installExtension,
      REDUX_DEVTOOLS,
    } = require("electron-devtools-installer");
    installExtension([REDUX_DEVTOOLS, reactDevToolsId])
      .then((name) => console.log(`Added Extension:  ${name}`))
      .catch((err) => console.log("An error occurred: ", err));
  }
  log.info("CREATING WINDOW...........");
  window = createWindow(directoryName, process, store, isDev);
  if (tray !== undefined) {
    tray.destroy();
  }

  tray = createTray(window, directoryName, process);
  createIpcBusBridge();

  app.on("activate", function () {
    /* 
      On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
      dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    */
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0)
      createWindow(window, tray, directoryName, process, store);
  });

  if (isDev === false) {
    autoUpdater.on("update-available", (_event, releaseNotes, releaseName) => {
      const dialogOpts = {
        type: "info",
        buttons: ["Ok"],
        title: "Application Update",
        message: process.platform === "win32" ? releaseNotes : releaseName,
        detail: "A new version is being downloaded.",
      };
      dialog.showMessageBox(dialogOpts, (response) => {});
    });

    autoUpdater.on("update-downloaded", (_event, releaseNotes, releaseName) => {
      const dialogOpts = {
        type: "info",
        buttons: ["Restart", "Later"],
        title: "Application Update",
        message: process.platform === "win32" ? releaseNotes : releaseName,
        detail:
          "A new version has been downloaded. Restart the application to apply the updates.",
      };
      dialog.showMessageBox(dialogOpts).then((returnValue) => {
        if (returnValue.response === 0) autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
      });
    });
  }
};

module.exports = { handleLaunch };
```

Here is the createWindow function as requested by Kiran Maniya

```
// Library Imports
const { BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const url = require("url");
const log = require("electron-log");
// Functions
const { handleResolutionPref } = require("./handleResolutionPref");
const { handlePositionPref } = require("./handlePositionPref");
const { maximizeWindow } = require("./maximizeWindow");
const { minimizeWindow } = require("./minimizeWindow");
const { closeWindow } = require("./closeWindow");

const createWindow = (directoryName, process, store, isDev) => {
  try {
    const [screenWidth, screenHeight] = handleResolutionPref(store);
    const [screenXCoordinate, screenYCoordinate, isScreenPositionCustom] =
      handlePositionPref(store);

    let window = null;
    const browserWindowOptions = {
      width: screenWidth,
      height: screenHeight,
      frame: false,
      fullscreenable: true,
      resizable: true,
      transparent: false,
      webPreferences: {
        preload: path.join(directoryName, "preload.bundle.js"),
        contextIsolation: false,
        nodeIntegration: true,
        sandbox: false,
        webSecurity: false,
      },
      icon: path.join(directoryName, "icon.ico"),
    };

    // Create the browser window.
    if (isScreenPositionCustom === true) {
      browserWindowOptions.x = screenXCoordinate;
      browserWindowOptions.y = screenYCoordinate;

      window = new BrowserWindow(browserWindowOptions);
    } else {
      window = new BrowserWindow(browserWindowOptions);
    }

    window.on("closed", () => (window = null));

    if (isDev === true) {
      window.loadURL("http://localhost:3000");
    } else {
      window.loadURL(
        url.format({
          pathname: path.join(directoryName, "index.html"),
          protocol: "file:",
          slashes: true,
        })
      );
    }

    // Handle window toggling for custom titlebar
    ipcMain.on("windowMinimize", () => minimizeWindow(window));
    ipcMain.on("windowMaximize", () => maximizeWindow(window));
    ipcMain.on("windowClose", () => closeWindow(window));

    // Open the DevTools.
    // window.webContents.openDevTools()

    return window;
  } catch (error) {
    log.info("CREATE WINDOW ERROR INSIDE FUNCTION: ", error);
  }
};

module.exports = { createWindow };
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Where are you trying to restart the app? Please remove [any unnecessary code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the example to help us help you, for example the dev-tool installation. Also - consider using `electron-builder` and its auto-update instead of Electron's built-in `autoUpdater`.

Comment: Please post the code of `createWindow` function to get better idea on the issue.

Comment: @Slbox I will look into using electron-builder's updater API. The reason I am trying to restart the app is sometimes when it is launching a IPC bridge that I instantiate fails. 

When it fails I want the application to attempt relaunching for a better user experience. However, my crash handler relaunches an Electron template rather than MY application. Hope that clears it up for you.

Comment: @FrankEdwards where is the crash coming from? A `renderer` or the `main` process? I might be able to provide a solution if you can clarify.

Comment: @Slbox the crash is occurring in the main process

Comment: Are you using `electron-unhandled` to catch otherwise uncaught errors? This would help you both prevent the crash and log the error so you can fix the issue.